# code for a PHP form that connects with a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, syntax

I am having problems with creating a PHP form for a web site that popluates a MySQL database.

Here is the error message I am getting at the following URL: http://www.laboro.biz/employer.php:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /hermes/bosoraweb013/b1108/ywh.tsarge83/laboro/employer-FormToEmail.php on line 228

The other file that is the action file is http://www.laboro.biz/employer-FormToEmail.php.

I need help with scripting to make this work.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: you will have to share your code.

Comment: Do you want to paste the code? From the error message, you're missing a closing brace or quote somewhere in your file, but it's quite hard to look without the code.

Comment: Just so you know, we can't see your PHP code from the links.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a curly brace somewhere in your script.

You're missing a `{` or have one more `}` or `;` than needed. Look it over.

Comment: Ah I believe `;` is the other case.